# Send post request with custom non JSON content in Python

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to create a post request to a specific url but the content I would like to pass is just simple text, not in JSON format, example:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.re
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 51
\r\n
I really like cheese, but I hate it in JSON format!
```

I've tried using the python *requests* module but it doesn't allow me to define the content to be just simple text.
I've found a similar question on stack overflow but it remains unanswered.

I would really appreciate help.

Comment: `reuqests` can `POST` whatever you like using `data=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify in headers your content type and use `data=`. Example:

```py
import requests

url = "https://httpbin.org/post"
text = "I really like cheese, but I hate it in JSON format!"

r = requests.post(url, headers={"Content-Type": "text/plain"}, data=text)
print(r.text)
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "I really like cheese, but I hate it in JSON format!", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Content-Length": "51", 
    "Content-Type": "text/plain", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.31.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-65292575-75a3fa092e6553300077b82c"
  }, 
  "origin": "127.0.0.1", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/delay/1"
}
```

Comment: I made similar answer, also using `httpbin.org`, but you were faster :)

Comment: @furas :) Just off-topic question: Is there something on httpbin.org for POST requests without the delay?

Comment: how about `https://httpbin.org/post` ? At least I tested my answer with this url.

Comment: @furas Yes, `/post` is better,  thanks -> I've edited my answer.

Comment: this worked, thank you very much. I am not sure if that's in the documentation cause I read it all and did not find it.